# How do I use Windows::Storage correctly in C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I am currently unable to call Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->RoamingFolder or Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings in Visual Studio 2015 targeting Windows 10.  My application is an Input Method Editor in the form of a dll, and I need a way to read from local storage to read the user's settings for the IME language.

[Windows::Storage::ApplicationData can't access its classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unKfZ.png)

Does anyone know why this is the case?  When I press F12 to "Go to Definition" (which works for Windows::Storage::ApplicationData but not for Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current), Visual Studio jumps to its definition within "windows.storage.h" instead of the Object Browser.

["Go To Definition" for the app I am working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfrpr.png)

"Go To Definition" for a Microsoft sample looks like this:  hxxp://i.stack.imgur.com/gecJh.png but with the hxxp corrected to http

I have tried adding a .cpp that calls Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->RoamingFolder which works in a different app to my .sln, where it shows the same errors, so I think there might be something about my configuration.  Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: retagged as c++-cli to get you a better pool of experts.

Comment: @user4581301 this has nothing to do with C++/CLI - I've rettaged this as C++/CX instead.

Comment: @HansPassant SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, 0, NULL, &FileName); fails for the IME when a UWP is active.  Are there any alternatives, or am I using SHGetKnownFolderPath incorrectly?

Comment: There are pretty draconian requirements for an IME to also be usable in a UWP app.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14964787/17034) has the essential link.  Do scratch the idea that you can poke a private user folder, can't happen.

Comment: My IME works perfectly fine otherwise in UWPs.  I'm not trying to access the user's %AppData% folder, just L"C:/Users/Dog/AppData/Local/Packages/Facebook.317180B0BB486_8xx8rvfyw5nnt/RoamingState/Settings.txt" or equivalent.  
A UWP (in this case, fb messenger) can access that location when it's hard coded into the IME; now I'm trying to do it for all UWP.  
What would be the proper way to access the RoamingState folder for a UWP?  I'll be using a helper .exe to copy settings from %AppData%\Roaming\IME\Settings.txt to each UWP's RoamingState folder.

Comment: So I know that UWPs' permissions are restricted; my problem is I don't know how to access the RoamingState folder to (one of) which their access is restricted.

Comment: Do you have any idea @HansPassant ?  Please help me; I have been laboring on this issue for 25 hours and still can't find a way to get a UWP open its own folder.